# How can we put a checkbox in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I created list of todos. Now I want to put the checkbox for each one cell. When I mark it as checked, it can be marked and then we select delete button if we want, which is also in the same cell at right side and deleted, but I am not able to perform action like this.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@Chakradhar not a big issue you can do it very easily with or without using custom images.

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate try to check and set the `UITableViewCellAccessory` as per your condition.

This is the way in which there is no need to use extra images and you can checked for you particular selected cell:

```
if (//here you check)
{   // item needed - display checkmark
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{   // not needed no checkmark
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Take this [**shopping tutorial**](http://technologyservants.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46:shopping-list-an-iphone-sqlite-tutorial&catid=13:opinion&Itemid=21) and see `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method see how they had used the condition.

**Edited as per your last comment:** For custom accessory view look for Implement a **[Custom Accessory View For UITableView in iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)**

Good Luck!

Comment: but how can we change that checkmark position from right to left

Comment: For that you have to go for custom accessory view...i had edited my answer for that

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but just so you know that first link is now dead

Comment: this Straight & Simple answer helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add custom button with an unchecked image on your cell. On button action method you can change the image to checked & handle rest of the things you want to handle.